# Variance of first return time markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

I have the following Markov Chain
 \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
   \frac{3}{5} & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{5}\\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
Now the question is. Let T be the time to, for the first time, arrive in state 1, after leaving from state 1. Calculate the expectation and variance of T. The first part I did, calculcating recursively led me to a mean first return time of  $\frac{31}{6}$. However I cannot figure out how to calculate the variance.

Edit: 
The first part I did like this.  
$u_{11}$ = 1 + $u_{21}$  
$u_{21}$ = 1 + $\frac{1}{3}u_{21}$ + $\frac{2}{3}u_{31}$  
$u_{31}$ = 1 + $u_{41}$  
$u_{41}$ = 1 + $\frac{2}{5}u_{41}$
and solving gives me $u_{11}$ = $\frac{31}{6}$.

Comment: Could you use the same kind of recursive computation to find the expected value of the first return time squared?

Comment: You mean like this: $u_{11}^2$ = $(1+u_{21})^2$?

Comment: You need to be careful to distinguish between random variables and their expected values.   It's not true in general that $E[X^{2}]=E[X]^{2}$.  You seem to be a bit confused by what exactly $u_{11}$ is.

Comment: Well I thought that $u_{11}$ is the expected number of steps it takes to arrive at state 1, departing from state 1. So $u_{11}$ = E[X] with X the number of steps needed to go from state 1 to state 1. Now I know that Var[X] = E[$X^2$] - $E[X]^2$. So what I need to know is  how to calculate E[$X^2$] ..

Comment: Can you explain to me how to go about this?